# Autosizing TextView - can I ignore the unexpected name prefix warning?

Tags: android, textview

I want to use autosizing text in my project and AS doesn't complain when i use the `android:` prefix. But since I want downwards compatibility, I use the app prefix. It works when the app is running, but the xml preview is buggy and I get the warning `Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag TextView`in every line that starts with `app:`.

Can I simply ignore that?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.exampleapp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_auto_size"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/autosize_text_sizes"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="200dp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to use an AppCompatTextView instead. Since you're using AppCompat features (which you do by accessing `app:*` (note that that particular namespace adds custom attributes, but the integrated ones that also are in the app namespace are usually AppCompat)) you have to use the AppCompatTextView as it supports these attributes

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_auto_size"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/autosize_text_sizes"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="200dp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Well I have that, but it's a different warning. This one is a warning about "unbound prefix" which wouldn't even let the app start. My attributes are underlined red, but they work when running.

Comment: @FlorianWalther add your entire XML file

Comment: Ok, the AppCompatTextView removes the errors, but since the documentation uses normal TextViews (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html) and since it still works, I wonder if I can just use a normal TextView.

Comment: @FlorianWalther AppCompatTextView extends TextView, you still get the same base features, but the class adds stuff for app compatibility. There's no significant differences between them that makes AppCompatTextView break compared to a regular TextView

Comment: Hey, I just found something interesting in the documentation of AppCompatTextView: "This will automatically be used when you use TextView in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView.html

So this is why it works - my Activity is an AppCompatActivity

Comment: Just tested it and indeed it stops working if I change my AppCompatActivity to Activity. THEN I need AppCompatTextView.

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned in comments, You should only need to manually use AppCompat classes when writing custom views: [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView)

So, there is no need to use AppCompatTextView instead of TextView inside your xml.

Simply, in your base application folder add `lint.xml` file and put the following lines into it to ignore "MissingPrefix" errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="MissingPrefix" severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

It will be also useful, if you use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) for example: https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/221